# solr 4's atomic updates insight

Tags: solr, lucene

Are atomic updates significantly faster than fetching data from a source and then making a whole new document and indexing it. Basically I would like to know how exactly solr's  atomic updates work?

Answer (score 2):

It actually reindexes the whole document, see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates.

Answer (score 1):

Atomic update could be faster because it does not involve fetching the current document from Solr first and then reposting the modified document. You can save on network time. Internally Solr will use the existing values for fields not specified in the atomic update (which is why you need to keep all values as stored).

Atomic update also helps you avoid conflicts since you need not worry if somebody else changes the document by the time you post your modified document. This problem could be dealt by using [optimistic concurrency](http://yonik.com/solr/optimistic-concurrency/) also.